# Input and output relation of ACS712 Hall effect current Sensor

Tags: arduino, current, components, current-measurement

ACS712 works by the use of the hall effect principle. When i went through the datasheet, i found out that the relation between input current and output voltage is varied largely ie. 66 mv/A to 185 mv/A.

But when i viewed to the tutorial regarding it's interface with Arduino, i found that in most of the tutorial they had assumed typical value ie. 185 mv/A.Is it correct ? Does the realtion between input current and output voltage depends on external parameter other than magnetic energy. Is there any way to minimize the range of input current and output voltage.

The relation is provided on the initial page in the category of Features and Benefits.

[Datasheet Link](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx)

[Link to the tutorial where typical value is assumed](http://arduinosensors.com/index.php/interfacing-a-hall-effect-current-sensor-with-an-arduino/)

Comment: Please post a link to the datasheet **in your question** and say where in the datasheet you see this. Then add a link to "the tutorial". Capital 'A' for _Arduino_. What do you mean by "IT"?

Comment: Edited. Tx for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACS712 is available in 3 versions with different ranges :- 5A, 20A, and 30A.

The 5A version (ACS712-X05B) is typically 185mV/A at 5V (ranging from 180 minimum to 190 maximum).

The 30A version (ACS712-x30A) is typically 66mV/A.

Comment: Yes this is the point. But when i refer the datasheet, i found  a varied range for it. And it messed me up.

Comment: Yes, the datasheet is confusing. In the 'Features and Benefits' summary at the top it says 66-180mV/A (which doesn't sound like a benefit!). You have to read down through the rest of the document to find out what they mean by that.

Comment: I digged up the datasheet. Even though i look at the typical performance characteristics graph and table value at Ip = 5 A max, i didnt find out any strong point supporting the above metioned feature. There's lies a fluctuation but it's within the benefical range( 185 (+- 5) A.

Comment: What i concluded is that the range defined above is for Ip = 5 A, 10 A and 20 A. So, for Ip = 5A, the range is between 180 mv/A and 190 mv/A. Plz give a look at the datasheet and help me to verify my search. Tx in advance.

Comment: Yes. This info is in the table on page 5:- 'x05B Performance Characteristics'. Note that this only applies to the ACS712-X05B.